# Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent + asp.net mvc + adfs signout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs2.0

I have implemented Signout functionality for an asp.net mvc application. I have a button called SignOut and for the button click I hooked the code in a Controller class as mentioned below:

```
public void SignOut()
                   {
                             try
                             {
                                      WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(null, null);                              
                             }
                             finally
                             {
                                      if (FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule != null)
                                                FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();
                             }
                   }
```

I am getting an error in the line `FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie();` as mentioned below :

**Error: Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent.**

Can anyone help me regarding the above issue.

Answer (score 0):

FederatedSignOut deletes the SessionTokenCookie and then redirects to the method parameter (which is your case is null).

So the "finally" clause is not required.

It works when you remove it, right?

Comment: I removed the finally clause containing the if (FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule != null) FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.DeleteSessionTokenCookie(); }. I have created a custom View called Signout( i.e Signout.cshtml) but is now throwing a jquery error :Object Expected with error numer :-2146823281. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I made a sample asp.net mvc3 application and implemented adfs authentication for it. Now I hooked the Signout functionality and found that the application was running fine. Then I found on analysis that there is a jquery plugin file (jquery.mobile-1.0.js) included in the project which is creating the jquery error to be popped up.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should return an [EmptyResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.emptyresult%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). For example:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("logoff", Name = "LogOff")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    WSFederationAuthenticationModule.FederatedSignOut(new Uri(FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Issuer), new Uri(FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.Reply));

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```